# How to write Shell Script to run a particular program every 24 hours?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I'd like to describe commands on shell script to do the following behaviors after booting Linux PC without daemon like cron.
(Only describe on "/etc/rc.local" with shell script Name)

1. After booting, count up the count up variable every one second automatically.    (No one logs in the Linux PC)
2. Passing 86400 counts(=24hours), have a particular program run.   (Not every fixed time, but passage of 24 hours after booting)
3. This behavior described in shell script runs in back ground with other tasks simultaneously.

Details about my Linux PC is as follows.

- OS : Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy)
- Shell : bash

Comment: Why don't you use `crontab` for this?

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the point but something with a loop including a sleep 86400 should do the trick (depending on the needed time by your process)

Comment: You don't even need a loop for this if it only needs to happen once.

Comment: As stated by @fedorqui `crontab` is a better approach in your case & pretty easy to set up too.

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciated your comments.

I know "crontab" is the easiest way to fill my requirements.

However, I'd like to user only commands (ex: while, do, some variables) on Shell Script.

Is therre anything to do this without daemons something like crontab?


Let me add.

Putting char '&' after command (including Name of Shell Script) on other Schell Script, 
 the behavior written in the Shell Script will be done in back ground.
Is it right?